# Remote HTTP to FTP

Tags: ftp, http

I am on a very slow download with the internet that I have and unfortunately I only have access to expensive and slow wireless or satelite.

I have set up an FTP with a computer supplier locally who has a nice 2 Mbps speed and am trying to set up a way of adding links remotely (Hotfile, rapidshare, Fileserve, etc.) so that they can be downloaded onto the FTP and then transfered a few times a week manually onto a portable HDD.

On my home PC I use Internet download manager for all my downloads. Is there a simple way that I can add links remotely to Internet Download Manager on the FTP or perhaps another solution? The OS on the FTP is Linux - I use Windows XP SP3 and Windows 7.

I have not used FTP very much before so any suggestions on how best to do this would be much appreciated.

Comment: FTP means File Transfer Protocol, and doesn't necessarily refer to a physical object like you seem to be. Is it just an FTP _server_ you have set up, or are you also able to SSH into the server and work from a command line?

Comment: Short answer: No. FTP and HTTP are different.

Comment: It is just a linx ftp server although I can have phsysical access to install software. I have seen "seedboxes" advertised alot which allow you to download files and torrents to which you can then access via ftp - So essentially I guess I am trying to set up my own seedbox although not really using it for seeding - just personal use.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have FTP access, you will not be able to initiate downloads from remote filesharing websites to the FTP server.

If you have shell (console) access, or the FTP server software allows sell commands, you can do just about everything.

For files available by regular HTTP download, you can use the `wget` or `curl` utilities. For files on filesharing sites, there are multiple download managers to choose from including FatRat, d4x, jdownloader, Download Manager, and the plethora of Windows software that runs in Wine. You can access the desktop of the server using VNC or similar to run these utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [www.autofilemove.com](http://www.autofilemove.com) to do what you want, you can download files from URL to your FTP directly. more about how to do this is there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSgqfeMl9is